# Unicode characters from database not recognized

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, unicode

This stumps me. I'm upgrading a fairly large app (for me) from Rails 2.3 to Rails 3.0. I'm also running this app in Ruby 1.9.2 as opposed to 1.8.7 before. On top of that I've also switched to HTML5. There are therefore many variables in play.

In several pages, the text coming from the MySQL database just does not display right anymore. This can be as simple as the euro symbol (€) or as esoteric as some Sanskrit text: सर्वम् मंगलम्

While everything looked great on the old site now I get some garbage characters such as ‚Ç¨ instead of the euro sign or the following:

```
‡§∏‡§∞‡•ç‡§µ‡§Æ‡•ç ‡§Æ‡§Ç‡§ó‡§≤‡§Æ‡•ç
```

... instead of the sanskrit text.

The data in the database is unchanged. As far as I know everything is set up for utf-8 everywhere.

What gives?

Edit 1 following up Roland's help:

Here is what I get on my ubuntu server's MySQL databases:

```
mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'character_set%';
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value                      |
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
| character_set_client     | latin1                     |
| character_set_connection | latin1                     |
| character_set_database   | latin1                     |
| character_set_filesystem | binary                     |
| character_set_results    | latin1                     |
| character_set_server     | latin1                     |
| character_set_system     | utf8                       |
| character_sets_dir       | /usr/share/mysql/charsets/ |
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
```

but here is what I get from running the command on my local mac:

```
mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'character_set%';
+--------------------------+------------------------------------------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value                                                |
+--------------------------+------------------------------------------------------+
| character_set_client     | utf8                                                 |
| character_set_connection | utf8                                                 |
| character_set_database   | utf8                                                 |
| character_set_filesystem | binary                                               |
| character_set_results    | utf8                                                 |
| character_set_server     | utf8                                                 |
| character_set_system     | utf8                                                 |
| character_sets_dir       | /usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.5.14/share/mysql/charsets/ |
+--------------------------+------------------------------------------------------+
```

The second listing looks better to me (who doesn't understand encoding very much).

Should I modify my server databases' settings? Won't that mess up their existing data? If so how do I go about changing the char. set variables?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you interpret the given string as Unicode, save it as UTF-8 to a byte stream and then convert the byte stream to MacRoman, you will get the right bytes. These are the UTF-8 encoded string.

I did this (in a UTF-8 terminal):

```
$ echo '‡§∏‡§∞‡•ç‡§µ‡§Æ‡•ç ‡§Æ‡§Ç‡§ó‡§≤‡§Æ‡•ç' > in
$ iconv -f UTF-8 -t MacRoman < in
सर्वम् मंगलम्
```

So somewhere, the opposite conversion is done to the data. The byte stream is interpreted as being in *MacRoman*, and it is then converted to UTF-8 again.

Comment: Nice, catch. Out of interest how did you work out that the bad encoding was MacRoman? (Experience, Wild Guess, Tried every encoding you could think of?)

Comment: Oh and good places to start checking for mismatched encodings are: your http headers to and from the web server, your mysql table settings, maybe your mysql client library settings in ruby.

Comment: MacRoman was my first guess. It couldn't be ISO-8859-1 because I know how the typical encoding errors look like. They usually involve an `Ã` as the first "wrong character", or something else from ISO-8859-1, and I know that encoding pretty much by heart. The fact that every third character in your example was the same was a big hint for something related to UTF-8. The rest was pure luck.

Comment: Okay, that's great and I +1ed the answer but I'm still not sure how to fix the problem in my Rails 3 app so that all characters look good on the site. Any hint by anyone? Michael?

Comment: I think you will have to follow your sanskrit string all the way from the database to the rendered HTML page. Pay attention to any code that converts a string from the native encoding (you are really on a Mac, are you?) to UTF-8.

Comment: Yes, I'm on a Mac. In the process to convert my site to Ruby 1.9.2 I had to convert a table to a different name. Since I had to manually change the table name in the myqsldump file before restoring it may be it happened at that time, while using Textmate. I'll look into it and let you know.

Comment: Roland, I added an edit to my question. I think the problem comes at the very beginning of the cycle, when I mysqldump the data. Do you think the settings I added to the post are key to this problem?

Comment: I cannot tell exactly, but yes, it looks like a good start. You need to be aware though that even when displaying the data in a terminal or saving it to a byte file, there are lots of encoding conversions involved. Especially when you save a file and load it later, the editor might guess that it has another encoding. It's a tricky thing.

Comment: Yes, the latter is exactly what happened. The problem is that I used Textmate to open the file and change the table names and it opens the file in Macroman. I'm now using a regular backup and trying to find another way to populate my new table. I'll use Mysql directly. Thanks a million for your help.